# How to write loop in Bash that will break on CTRL+C?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, break

I've try this code:

```
ls | while read file; do mpg123 "$file" || break; done
```

but when I press <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>, it play next song. How can I break on <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that when you press <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> (`SIGINT`), `mpg123` is the one that catches it, and returns with status `0`, so your shell won't receive the signal and therefore it won't abort the loop.

You can just keep <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> pressed until playback has stopped to break out of the loop.

Or use a different player. `mplayer` for example seems to exit with status `1` on <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd>, so that should work.

That said, you could rewrite your command in a more elegant way using [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

```
ls | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 mplayer
```

Answer (score 1):

If you for some reason prefer a while loop, e.g. you want to print out the file name or change it somehow, then you can make bash trap the SIGINT (Ctrl+C) by first backgrounding the process and then  `wait`ing for it, now `wait` will be the one to catch SIGINT instead of `process`:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -print0 |
while read -r -d '' f; do
    echo "$f"
    process "$f" > "$f.processed" &
    wait $!
done
```

(`find -print0` with `read -d ''` will support strange filenames with newlines and whatnot, add `-maxdepth 1` to find if you want to exclude subdirectories)